# Object + subject + verb pattern

Tags: prepositions, writing-style, sentence-patterns

I have problems with the following pattern Object + subject + verb + preposition.  For example, the simple sentence,

**Things I’ve been struggling with.**

The idea is that I'm not sure if that pattern is informal, or it's standard English. I would say something like,

**I've been struggling with some things.**

I recognize that in that sentence we must use an object, but I'm not sure when I can use either of the two patterns.
This confusion happens when I encounter sentences with verb + preposition without an object after preposition. Another example would be,

**I learned that the people that they work for often are the people they are afraid of.**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Things that I've been struggling with"

Comment: With or without _that_, "Things I've been struggling with" is not a sentence, not even a simple one. It's a noun phrase with a modifying relative clause..

Comment: But *Things I’ve been struggling with.* isn't a well formed sentence, so I'm not sure how to construe the rest of the question.